# Front-end delete account in Wordpress

Tags: front-end, customization, account

is there a way for a registered user in Wordpress to have in his author page an option to **delete** his account along with his posts without going to dahsboard?

I need a front-end option in a form of a button for user to be able to delete his profile :)

Thank You in advance for Your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at  [**`wp_delete_user`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user) , all you need to do is pass the author's id and his posts will be deleted along with its account.